# How to calculate the variance of the integral of a stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose $X(t)$ is an O-U process. We define $f(t,X(t))=\pi(t,X(t))(X(t)+a)$, where a is a constant. Now I need to calculate the variance of $\int_{s}^{T}\pi[(X(t)+a)dt+bdW(t)]$. Here a and b are both constants, W(t) is a standard wiener process.

I calculate $Var(\int_{s}^{T}\pi[(X(t)+a)dt+bdW(t)])=Var(\int_{s}^{T}f(t,X(t))dt+b\pi(t,X(t)) dW(t))$.

Firstly, I calculate $E[\int_{s}^{T}f(t,X(t))dt+b\pi(t,X(t)) dW(t)]=E[\int_{s}^{T}f(t,X(t))dt]$.

Then I calculate $E[(\int_{s}^{T}f(t,X(t))dt+b\pi(t,X(t)) dW(t))^{2}]=E[\int_{s}^{T}(f(t,X(t))dt+b\pi(t,X(t)) dW(t))^{2}]=E[\int_{s}^{T}b^{2}\pi^{2}dt]$

Therefore, I think the variance of $\int_{s}^{T}\pi[(X(t)+a)dt+bdW(t)]$ is $E[\int_{s}^{T}b^{2}\pi^{2}dt]-(E[\int_{s}^{T}f(t,X(t))dt])^{2}$. But the answer is given as $Var[\int_{s}^{T}b\pi(t,X(t)) dW(t)]$.

Could you give me any hint where i am wrong? It seems the difference is comes from $(E[\int_{s}^{T}f(t,X(t))dt])^{2}$. The answer seems to say that this part is equal to 0, but I don't get it.

Comment: I am confused on the definition $f(t,X(t))=\pi\cdot (t,X(t))(X(t)+a)$.  Is $\pi=3.14....$? If so, the quantity $(t,X(t))$ is a vector.

Comment: \pi is a function here not a constant, \pi(t,X(t)) should be seen as a whole

Comment: ok because later on you just write $\pi^{2}$. So I am guessing whenever you just wrote $\pi$, you actually meant to write the full $\pi(t,X_t)$.

Comment: Can you add some details on what regularities you have for $\pi$? Eg. is it Lipschitz? L2-integrable.

Comment: actually, $\pi$ is a process from a stochastic optimal control problem. My problem is from the derivation step from: $$\operatorname{Var}_t\left[\int_t^T \pi^*(s)\left\{\left[k(\theta-X(s))+\frac{1}{2} \eta^2+\rho \sigma \eta\right] d s+\eta d W(s)\right\}\right]$$ to $$
\operatorname{Var}_t\left[\int_t^T \pi^*(s) \eta d W(s)\right]
$$

Comment: I am so confused since how could the first term be 0?

Comment: ok, can you add all the details in your above post, including those comments and references so that we can go read about the particular stochastic control problem you have in mind?